# Jest testing fails: Should use Material-UI for all react components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-component

I'm working on a project using React, I'm using Material-UI just for the components that contains forms. When i run the test, the components with forms (which uses material UI) is passing successfully, but the problem is with the components that there's no forms in it, so it's not using any material ui components, the test fails!

When i run the test, it's not passing these components and shows:

```
  ● Natural

    Material-UI: expected an Element but found null. Please check your console for additional warnings and try fixing those. If the error persists please file an issue.

       5 | 
       6 | test('Natural', () => {
    >  7 |   const story = renderer.create(<BrowserRouter> <Story /> </BrowserRouter>).toJSON();
         |                          ^
       8 |   expect(story).toMatchSnapshot();
       9 | });
      10 |
```

This is my test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Story from './index';

test('Natural', () => {
  const story = renderer.create(<BrowserRouter> <Story /> </BrowserRouter>).toJSON();
  expect(story).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

And this is my components code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Footer from '../Common/Footer';

const Story = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <main>
        <h1>Hello Story page!</h1>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Story;
```

I expect the test to be passed!

Comment: Try to import all the material Ui in your test cases too.Also try to check whether the component is rendering using console.log(window.debug(story)) above your expect line in the test case

Comment: Thanks @HemaNandagopal! But no change after i did what u told me :\

Comment: What is in Footer?

Comment: I don't think you should see this message unless something in `Footer` is using a Material-UI component. Based on the message (which I believe only exists in v4, so I assume that is what you are using), I would expect that the `Footer` is using Material-UI's `Button` or something else that leverages `ButtonBase`.

Comment: Oh @RyanCogswell !! You're right, I'm using `Material UI` in the `Footer`, I've missed that. Do you have any idea can help to solve this?

Comment: I’m assuming you are using a v4 beta version. I think if you update to the rc.0 (released this week) it should be fixed.

Comment: Really thanks for this great solution, I've just tried this before your comment, that solved the problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the version of the Material UI package. I was using `v4.0.0-beta.2`, but now i've updated it to `v4.0.0-rc.0` and that solved the problem and all the test passed.

Another note, that i was using material ui on my `Footer` component. So the problem will be shown on the component that I use Material UI components on it.

---

Edit:

New version released: `v4.0.1`